# Mergesort Python implementation

Tags: python, mergesort

I have seen a lot of mergesort Python implementation and I came up with the following code. The general logic is working fine, but it is not returning the right results. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
def merge(left, right):
    temp = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            temp.append(left[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            temp.append(right[j])
            j = j + 1
    print("i = ", i, "j = ", j)
    while i < len(left):
        temp.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(right):
        temp.append(right[j])
        j += 1
    print("Returned from merge", temp)
    return temp

def mergesort(data):
    if len(data) < 2:
        return
    left = data[:len(data)//2]
    print(left)
    right = data[len(data)//2:]
    print(right)
    print("left only now")
    mergesort(left)
    print("right now")
    mergesort(right)
    return merge(left, right)

data = mergesort([1, 20, 30, 25, 8, 7, 9])
```

In the main *mergesort* function I think the last line is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *mergesort* function you call doesn't modify its argument. Rather, it returns a new sorted list.

A simple fix would be:

```py
def mergesort(data):
    if len(data) < 2:
        return data              # Fix1
    left = data[:len(data)//2]
    print(left)
    right = data[len(data)//2:]
    print(right)
    print("left only now")
    left = mergesort(left)       # Fix2
    print("right now")
    right = mergesort(right)     # Fix3
    return merge(left,right)

data = mergesort([1,20, 30, 25, 8, 7, 9])
```

Comment: But it also a violation of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) (bad habits carried over from C).