# I am not getting the correct output for merge sort in Python

Tags: python, mergesort

I am trying to writing the algorithm for [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) in Python, but I am not getting the correct output. The error I am getting is "list assignment index out of range", so there is some logical error.

This is my code:

```
def mergeSort(a, l, r):
if l < r:
    mid = (l+r)//2
    mergeSort(a, l, mid)
    mergeSort(a, mid+1, r)
    merge(a, l, mid, r)


def merge(a, l, mid, r):
    b = []
    i = l
    j = mid + 1
    k = l
    while i <= mid and j <= r:
        if a[i] < a[j]:
            b[k] = a[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            b[k] = a[j]
            j = j + 1

    k = k + 1

if i > mid:
    while j <= r:
        b[k] = a[j]
        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1
else:
    while i <= mid:
        b[k] = a[i]
        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1

for k in range(l, r+1):
    a[k] = b[k]


a = []
n = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
print("Enter the elements now")
    for i in range(0, n):
    element = int(input())
    a.append(element)

print("Given array: ", a)

mergeSort(a, 0, len(a) - 1)
print("Sorted array is: ", a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mergesort python implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58480851/mergesort-python-implementation)

Comment: For debugging help, you need to include the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). For reference see [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Also, I see at least three indentation errors. You need to provide working code. (ref: [mre])

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code to what it actually is at the source? Please [edit (change) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70105943/edit) (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that the array out of bounds error is coming because you are using **`b = []`**. When you do **`b[k] = a[i]`**, it will throw the out of bounds exception. You have to initialize the **`b`** array.

Secondly, there are some issues in the logic. I corrected your code as follows:

```
def mergeSort(a):
    if len(a) > 1:
        mid = len(a) // 2
        L = a[:mid]
        R = a[mid:]
        mergeSort(L)
        mergeSort(R)
        merge(a, mid, L, R)


def merge(a, mid, L, R):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
        if L[i] < R[j]:
            a[k] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            a[k] = R[j]
            j = j + 1

        k = k + 1

    while j < len(R):
        a[k] = R[j]
        k = k + 1
        j = j + 1
    while i < len(L):
        a[k] = L[i]
        k = k + 1
        i = i + 1

a = []
n = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
print("Enter the elements now")
for i in range(0, n):
    element = int(input())
    a.append(element)

print("Given array: ", a)

mergeSort(a)
print("Sorted array is: ", a)
```